# I want to send object of my model class from activity-one to activity-three directly. How can this will be achieved?

Tags: android

There are 3 activities named activity-one, activity-two and activity-three. Clicking next on activity-one takes you to the activity-two and then next on activity-two takes you to activity-three. So, I want to send **object of my model class** from **activity-one to activity-three directly**. How can this will be achieved?

Comment: there is no *good* way to do that. A good way would be to send it through intents with activity-2 in the middle. The bad way can be using a static field in the activity 3 for example

Comment: If you are going trough `activity one->two->three` then why are you not sending data to `activity two->three`?

Comment: Either you can propagate your model from A -B - C. Its the most conventional and android way. Another way is you can make a method in your application class to hold your model .Set it from Activity  A and fetch it again from Activity C

Comment: @p.mathew13 can give some example for making method to hold model?

Comment: use static variable

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736389/how-to-pass-an-object-from-one-activity-to-another-on-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
My ApplicationClass extends Application{
 private Model model;
 public static void setModel(Model model){
 this.model=model
 }

 public static Model getModel{
 return model
}
}
```

You can use generics to generify this function to handle any kind of model classes

Comment: And specify the android:name property in the the <application> node in AndroidManifest.xml:

`<application 
   android:name=".MyCustomApplication"
   android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
   android:label="@string/app_name" 
   ...>`

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using

> SharedPreferences

like this

In Activity one

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, 
MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("name", "Elena");
editor.putInt("idName", 12);
editor.apply();
```

In Third Activity

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);
if (restoredText != null) {
 String name = prefs.getString("name", "No name defined");//"No name defined" is the 
 default value.
 int idName = prefs.getInt("idName", 0); //0 is the default value.
}
```