# Passing Parcelable object which has a member variable which is Not parcelable(a class that belongs to third party library)

Tags: android, parcelable, parcel

I'm trying to send a class's object(let's say Class X's object) as part of class that implements Parcelable.
The problem that I am facing here is, `Class X` is a part of some library and I can not edit it to implement Parcelable or serializable.
I've checked that `Class X` does not implement Parcelable or serializable and we can not change as well.
Can you guys please help me here?

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Start the service.
        DummyParcelableObject mObj = new DummyParcelableObject(new RandomClass(2019));
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SampleService.class);
        serviceIntent.putExtra("myObj", mObj);
        startService(serviceIntent);
    }
}
```

Dummy Parcelable class:

```
class DummyParcelableObject implements Parcelable {

    RandomClass mRandomClass;

    public DummyParcelableObject(RandomClass obj) {
        mRandomClass = obj;
    }

    protected DummyParcelableObject(Parcel in) {
        mRandomClass = (RandomClass) in.readValue(RandomClass.class.getClassLoader());
    }

    public static final Creator<DummyParcelableObject> CREATOR = new Creator<DummyParcelableObject>() {
        @Override
        public DummyParcelableObject createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new DummyParcelableObject(in);
        }

        @Override
        public DummyParcelableObject[] newArray(int size) {
            return new DummyParcelableObject[size];
        }
    };

    public int getRandomVar() {
        int n = 0;

        if (mRandomClass != null)
        {
            System.out.println("Anil: DummyParcelableObject: if (mRandomClass != null) is true.\n");
            n = mRandomClass.getNumb();
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Anil: DummyParcelableObject: if (mRandomClass != null) is false.\n");
        }

        return n;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeValue(mRandomClass);
    }
}
```

Class X that is part of another library:

```
class RandomClass{
    public static int cnt = 0;
    private int nRandomNumber = 0;
    public RandomClass(int n)
    {
        nRandomNumber = n;
    }

    public int getNumb()
    {
        return nRandomNumber;
    }
}
```

Service that we need to send the data to:

```
public class SampleService extends Service {
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startid) {
        DummyParcelableObject obj = intent.getParcelableExtra("mObj");
        if (obj == null) {
            System.out.println("\nAnil: ParcelableExtra is null");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("\nAnil: ParcelableExtra is not null");
            System.out.println("\nAnil: obj.getRandomVar() = " + obj.getRandomVar());
        }

        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

Comment: check if the class implements serializable if yes make your class serializable and proceed.

Comment: That class does not implement serializable or parcelable. and we can not change as well because it belongs to third party library.

Comment: In that case, use a static method in your application class to set and get your data object like : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56273846/5571700

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot implement `Parcelable` or `Serializable`, there is only one option left: passing the object through global state.

## Using static fields

Add a static field of the type `RandomClass` to `DummyParcelableObject`, e.g. `randomClassStatic`. Set it just before starting the service:

```
// Start the service.
DummyParcelableObject mObj = new DummyParcelableObject(new RandomClass(2019));
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SampleService.class);
serviceIntent.putExtra("myObj", mObj);
DummyParcelableObject.randomClassStatic = mObj.getRandomClass();
startService(serviceIntent);
```

Then retrieve it right after the service started in `onStartCommand()`:

```
DummyParcelableObject obj = intent.getParcelableExtra("mObj");
obj.setRandomClass(DummyParcelableObject.randomClassStatic);
DummyParcelableObject.randomClassStatic = null;
```

You would need to define `getRandomClass()` and `setRandomClass()` accordingly for getting / setting `mRandomClass`.

Note that this is not the safest thing to do in regard of concurrency, objects' life cycles, etc…

## Using the `Application` class

This can only be used if you have access to an `Activity` or `Service` on both ends.

Subclass `Application` and add a field of type `RandomClass` to it. It will serves as relay. Define public methods for getting / setting this field (e.g. `getRandomClass()` and `setRandomClass()`). Do not forget to reference your subclassed `Application` in the manifest as described [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/app/Application?hl=en). Before starting the service:

```
// Start the service.
DummyParcelableObject mObj = new DummyParcelableObject(new RandomClass(2019));
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SampleService.class);
serviceIntent.putExtra("myObj", mObj);
((MyApplication) getApplication()).setRandomClass(mObj.getRandomClass());
startService(serviceIntent);
```

Then for retrieving the object once the service started, still in `onStartCommand()`:

```
DummyParcelableObject obj = intent.getParcelableExtra("mObj");
obj.setRandomClass(((MyApplication) getApplication()).getRandomClass());
DummyParcelableObject.randomClassStatic = null;
```

This has the benefit of not using a static field, but can still be a source of bugs if handled poorly (thread safety, no checks on nullity, …).