# Selector for Cloudant is not Parcelable

Tags: android, parcelable, cloudant

I try to pass Selector from an activity to another via intent, with this code:

```
Selector mSelector = gt("_id", 0);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_QUERY_SELECTOR, mSelector);
```

I get this error message Parcel: unable to marshal value.
I have tried this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/56523680/1564762) without sucess! 
Is it possible to pass Selector (com.cloudant.client.api.query.Selector) to another activity?

I can do:

```
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_QUERY_SELECTOR, mSelector.toString());
```

but then I can't convert back to Selector.

All this for later be used in:

```
db.query
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this instead:

```
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_QUERY_SELECTOR, new QueryBuilder(mSelector).build());
```